# call external dll in assembler (reverse engineer)

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, code-injection, ida, codecave

I have a exe file of a game that I like to add some implementation.

To do this I need to add a "jump" in assembler that execute a function from a external dll.

I need to add the jump inside the function:

```
int __cdecl sub_43AC70(char *a1, int a2)
{
  call my_function(a1) from mylibrary.dll

  int i; // [esp+0h] [ebp-4h]

  for ( i = sub_43BC50(); i; i = *(_DWORD *)i )
  {
    if ( *(_DWORD *)(i + 88) == a2 && (!a1 || !stricmp((const char *)(i + 4), a1)) )
      return i;
  }
  return 0;
```

[image]

[image]

I don't have experience in assembler and I don't known how is hard add this jump.

For the moment I have found this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80bjkJcCQO4&feature=emb_logo

that execute an external exe, that is not exactly what I need ...

However if there is a way to execute an external exe from a command line with a paramter:

call myprogram.exe -a1

in assembler , can be a compromise, so instead of create a dll with a parameter I can create a command line with a parameter, both are a good solution.

Can you please tell me a assembly code that execute a function with a parameter from external dll or excecute a external command line with a parameter ?

thanks !

Comment: Is the dll already loaded? The simplest way to achieve what you want is to write a short C program, compile it, disassemble it with Ida, copy the function/sub into your binary and then execute this function.

Comment: Hi, Robert, thank you ! I can't do it, the dll or a command line will be write in C# or Vb.net and will be add force feedback support and other things, too much long and complicated to put inside the original game exe. I searching for the assemply code to call a function of a external dll. ex. call my_function(variabile1) from mylibrary.dll